# Command Pattern persistence and Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, macros

I want to record a sequence of commands to a data store and save them so I can replay them on the store later.  I have a command interface:

```
interface ICommand { void Execute(); }
```

I have different classes implementing the ICommand, say

```
class Create: ICommand {...}
class Update: ICommand {...}
class Delete: ICommand {...}
class Save: ICommand {...}
...
```

I can make a "macro" as a sequence of commands:

```
List<ICommand> macro = new List<ICommand> {...};
```

Now I want to persist the macro in somewhere, like a file, or a column in a database.  My first thought is that the XmlSerializer is one way to move the macro to a stream.   I can mark the command classes [Serializable], and Deserialize and Serialize provide a cheap way to get some persistence, yes?  No.

The first issue is that classes with no state result in empty streams.  The Save command, for instance, takes no parameters and returns nothing.  The information I am trying to capture is that there was a request to Save the system state, and I don't have to know anything about what it was I was saving.  If I

```
ICommand save = new Save();
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Save));
serializer.Serialize(target, save)
serializer.Deserialize(target);
```

I get an exception, because an empty string doesn't have a root.  I haven't even really started to think about needing to know the type of the command I am deserializing before I do it, or how to handle deserializing the heterogeneous list once I do manage to save it.  Am I on the wrong track?  Is there a better way to persist commands in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first exception you got,
you need to have root element when you use `XmlSeralizer`
something like that

```
string rootElement = "Command"; 
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Save), new XmlRootAttribute(rootElement));
```

if you use streamwriter to test out, which is quite straight forward, it will work.

```
var save = new Save();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\output.xml"))
    s.Serialize(writer, save);

Save getSave = null;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\output.xml"))
    getSave = s.Deserialize(reader) as Save;
```

Comment: new XmlSerializer will create new serialization assembly on each call. Cache it